# "No wireless interfaces found"

Tags: linux

I accidentally ran the code on my terminal:

```
sudo airmon-ng check kill
```

Now when I try to connect to a wi-fi it says "No wireless interfaces found"
I tried to edit /etc/network/interfaces but everything is the way it must be.
What do I have to do?

Comment: On my `RPi 3B+` running `Raspbian stretch lite 2018-03-13` I cannot find a program named `airmon-ng`. What operating system you are running on what hardware?

Comment: `sudo reboot` .

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation that can be found [here](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airmon-ng)
Says, the command:

```
Sudo airmon-ng check kill
```

Will “stop network managers then kill interfering processes left” which means that your raspberry pi’s ability to connect to wifi will be disabled. I would recommend you either reboot the whole system with the following command

```
Sudo reboot
```

Or restart the pis, network interface with the following command:

```
service networking restart
```